# Is the minimum moment of inertia always about the center of mass?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I know this is true for an object with even dispersed mass, when each infinitesimal has the same mass about the axis you are considering. But is it also true for non-uniform mass.

Even just a short, correct, answer would be great. I was unable to find this anywhere online.

Comment: cf [Steiner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem)

Comment: Yes. MMOI transforms rot. speed to ang. momentum. Angular momentum about the center of mass is minimal, as any other location includes the moment of linear momentum $\vec{r} \times \vec{p}$.

Answer (score 4):

By parallel axis theorem, the moment of inertia should be minimum about an axis passing through the CM, no matter it's symmetric or not.

For suppose the moment of inertia about a certain axis which does not pass through its CM is $I$, then by parallel axis theorem, the moment of inertia with respect to a parallel axis through the CM is $I - Mh^2$ where $M$ is the total mass of the object and $h$ is the distance between the two axes.

As for moment of inertia about points, because they are tensors, it depends on how you define large and small.

Comment: I believe the question asks about *minimum* moment of inertia

Comment: Yes, is the minimum always at the center of mass is the question.

Comment: What do you mean by at the center of mass?

Comment: Moment of inertia and center of mass are two different things. But the moment of inertia is often lowest when taken about the center of mass. The question is whether this is always the case.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume the OP refers to the _axial_ moment of inertia, so that no tensors are involved. Under this assumption I find the first part of the answer accurate enough.

Comment: The comments have taken me for quite a ride. "Oh good, an answer to my question." "Oh good, somebody else is asking about the distinction." "Oh, they're not *always* the same." "bla bla bla tensors bla bla bla" - nvm. Thank you for the answer - saved me from having to type of the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The parallel axis theorem states that Moment of inertia about an axis parallel to the moment of inertia about an axis passing through COM is given by $$I=I_{cm}+Mx^2$$ so obviously MOI is minimum about an axis passing through COM